# FragmentStateAdapter doesn't show the fragments with arguments after recycling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to migrate to FragmentStateAdapter but got a problem with showing fragments.
When I first load the adapter, the createFragment() has been called for each Fragment. So from the beginning, I'm seeing the fragments with the correct data. But when I swipe back and forth - the first fragment start to be a blank white screen and if I do one more swipe again, the second page has an empty blank page too.
I tried to set a background color as a def param in the parent view to check is the fragment is still has been restored from the fragment manager. The result shows that yes - they are there but because I'm using arguments to declare the type that will be displayed in this fragment - after recycling the arguments are not exists anymore and that's why I see the blank white page.

Correct me if I'm wrong and what solution will fit better here?
Thanks

```
class ReviewContractAdapter(activity: FragmentActivity, private val cacheDirAbsolutePath: String):
    FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    companion object {
        const val REVIEW_CONTRACT_NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 2
        const val CONTRACT = "Contract"
        const val PAD = "PAD"
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = REVIEW_CONTRACT_NUMBER_OF_PAGES

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return PdfViewerFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                when (position) {
                    0 -> putString(CONTRACT_FILE_PATH, cacheDirAbsolutePath + CONTRACT_PATH)
                    else -> putString(PAD_FILE_PATH, cacheDirAbsolutePath + PAD_PATH)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using Activity to init the Adapter
Nothing special there

```
review_contract_viewpager.adapter = adapter
    TabLayoutMediator(review_contract_tabs, review_contract_viewpager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = when (position) {
            0 -> ReviewContractAdapter.CONTRACT
            else -> ReviewContractAdapter.PAD
        }
    }.attach()
```

Comment: Are you actually using your `ReviewContractAdapter` directly in an Activity? Or you are using it in another Fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake In an Activity. I added the code from it above. Maybe it's better to open an issue in the viewpager section directly?